# Upload Video on YouTube (via API) but visible only my website

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am developing a web applications for Education Video Tutorial.

I am using `YouTube Data API` to upload video on `YouTube` from my website.

I want to know that if it is possible to limit the visibility of the the uploaded videos to my website only and should not display on `YouTube`. But it can play using `YouTube Player` on my site.

Is there any such property/parameter on YouTube to hide your videos from YouTube search but can be played on my website ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the video as 'unlisted' which means that people cannot search for it in youtube but you will be able to embed it on your website, the downside of it is people with right link will be able to view it on youtube.

You can also embed private videos but there is a restriction of 50 users. These are the only two option available to you